# Do t-test of two sample groups with variance 0

Tags: variance, t-test

I'm trying to do a Welch's t-test of two sample groups which turn to have estimated variance equal to 0.

As could be seen from wikipedia page of Welch's t-test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test, the formula for calculating the t-stat:

$$ t= \frac{\overline X_1 - \overline X_2}{\sqrt{\frac{s_1^2}{N_1} +\frac{s_2^2}{N_2}}} $$
 contains 0 at the denominator and the t-stat could not be calculated (obviously my C++ program retuns me a NaN value...)

I need a way to handle this an calculate the t-test anyway, could you tell me how to proceed in these cases?

Comment: What do mean by handling the t-test?

Comment: I mean that I need to calculate the t statistic anyway in order to do the t-test

Comment: If the variance is zero, then all the values are *identical* -- is it true?

Comment: In my data I've found very similar samples, but not identical...

Comment: Also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86618.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way to handle this an calculate the t-test anyway

You can't. *t* is undefined. [See here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223579/what-do-you-expect-a-2-sample-t-test-for-the-same-two-samples-to-return)